# WriteableBitmap failing badly, pixel array very inaccurate

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, writeablebitmap

I have tried, literally for hours, and I have not been able to budge this problem.

I have a UserControl, that is 800x369, and it contains, simply, a path that forms a worldmap.
I put this on a landscape page, then I render it into a WriteableBitmap.
I then run a conversion to turn the 1d Pixels array into a 2d array of integers.
Then, to check the conversion, I wire up the custom control's click command to use the Point.X and Point.Y relative to the custom control in the newly created array.
My logic is thus:

```
wb = new WriteableBitmap(worldMap, new TranslateTransform());
wb.Invalidate();
intTest = wb.Pixels.To2DArray(wb.PixelWidth);
```

My conversion logic is as such:

```
public static int[,] To2DArray(this int[] arr,int rowLength)
{
    int[,] output = new int[rowLength, arr.Length / rowLength];
    if (arr.Length % rowLength != 0) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        output[i % rowLength, i / rowLength] = arr[i];
    }
return output;
}
```

Now, when I do the checking, I get completely and utterly strange results: apparently all pixels are either at values of -1 or 0, and these values are ***completely independent*** of the original colours.

Just for posterity: here's my checking code:

```
private void Check(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point click = e.GetPosition(worldMap);
    ChangeNotification(intTest[(int)click.X,(int)click.Y].ToString());
}
```

The result show absolutely no correlation to the path that the WriteableBitmap has rendered into it. The path has a fill of solid white.

What the heck is going on? I've tried for hours with no luck. Please, this is the major problem stopping me from submitting my first WP7 app. Any guidance?

Comment: Please zip up your project so we can test this more easily.

Comment: I've given up, I no longer have the code available either. Can we get close votes running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works correctly, Silverlight uses pre-multiplied ARGB, so for transparent each of the RGB values will get multiplied by 0 and the final result will be 0. For white you get four 255 bytes which is -1 because of how integers are represented. You can get the bytes from an int using the BitConverter class but I'd recommend [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) which has Get/SetPixel methods and handles the the pre-multiplication for you.

If you were just looking for hex values:

`ChangeNotification(intTest[(int)click.X,(int)click.Y].ToString("X8"));`

Comment: No no no! It DOESN'T work, because the values I get back have absolutely NO correlation to the actual pixels of the path! One white pixel would be a -1, another would be a zero! Same for empty space!

Comment: I haven't found a problem with your code. Try using the extensions I linked to that way you could set a pixel green on click and see if there is an issue with any transforms.

Comment: Another thing to check is that your Check method is being called when you click on a transparent area. If not set Background="Transparent" on the LayoutRoot in your UserControl. Also where in your code do you create the WriteableBitmap? (I'm doing it in the Loaded event)